# Does GCC have features to detect use-after-free bugs?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Here is my code snippet:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char key;          // value
    struct node *next; // pointer to the next element
} Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->key = 'K';
    n->next = NULL;

    free(n);

    printf("%c\n", n->key);
}
```

When the above snippet is compiled and run...

```
ganningxu@Gannings-Computer:~/test$ gcc test_faults.c -o test_faults; ./test_faults
K

ganningxu@Gannings-Computer:~/test$ clang test_faults.c -o test_faults; ./test_faults
K
```

There are no compiler warnings or errors when the freed memory is accessed. Is there any way to force the compiler to show such errors?

Comment: No. Use a debugging tool like `valgrind`.

Comment: Compiler does not care about memory management in general. Its job is to translate the C code into machine code

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think he means force it to generate code that produces errors.

Comment: One commonly used *workaround* is to set the pointer to `NULL` right after `free` ... `free(x); x = NULL;`

Comment: All the above comments are wrong. GCC can trivially detect this exact example with the correct compiler warning, -Wuse-after-free: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mhbd6h5dW

Comment: It's also possible to use the more powerful (but slower) -fanalyzer feature: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/35c5WY33E

Comment: And the equivalent with clang, --analyze: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a9EMTMoxx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When compiling with GCC, you can use [`-fsanitize=address` so that “Memory access instructions are instrumented to detect out-of-bounds and use-after-free bugs.”](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options) This will of course affect program performance, and it may also change the program behavior if there are bugs.