# How to avoid undefined behavior after deleting memory pointed to by a pointer in C++ when using multiple pointers assigned to same memory loacation?

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, memory-management, undefined-behavior

I'm experiencing undefined behavior after deleting memory pointed to by a pointer in C++. How can I avoid this issue when using multiple pointers assigned to the same memory location?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
private:
    int data;
public:
    MyClass(int d) : data(d) {}

    int getData() const {
        return data;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass *ptr = new MyClass(5);

    cout << "Data using pointer: " << ptr->getData() << endl;   
 
    MyClass *anotherPtr = ptr;

    delete ptr;
    
    cout << "Data using another pointer after deletion: " << anotherPtr->getData() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: never use raw `new` or `delete`. Use smart pointers

Comment: anyhow, I do not quite understand the quesiton. You know that  `anotherPtr->getData()` is wrong when the object has been deleted, so just dont do it. The quesiton seems to hinge on the false premise that `MyClass *anotherPtr = ptr; delete ptr;` is a sensible thing to do

Comment: Determine which object or objects are responsible for managing the pointed-at object. If there is one clear [owner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49024982/4581301), use a `std::unique_ptr` and ensure that is has a broader scope than all of the non-owning users. If there is no clear one owner or broad-enough scope cannot be guaranteed, use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: There is **no** way to avoid UB if the program uses an object after deletion.

Comment: There is also **nothing** you can reliably test to ensure the object still exists. All you can do is make sure it is not used after deletion with good code.

Comment: Undefined behavior must be avoided before you start compiling.  There is no way at runtime to recover from it. That is why unit testing and debugging are needed.

Comment: Also note you only need dynamically allocate a class when you have dynamic polymorphism (and then use std::make_unique/std::make_shared as mentioned above). In most other cases use STL containers, and move semantics.

Comment: "Doctor, Doctor it hurts when I do this!" - "Then don't do that!".   In general, a program doesn't work if you do stupid things in the code. So don't.

Comment: *How can I avoid this issue when using multiple pointers assigned to the same memory location?*  You avoid that problem by not doing that.  Once the dynamic object is deleted, all pointers to that dynamic object are invalidated.  Dereferencing them is undefined behavior.  (I believe *even accessing the pointer itself* after the object has been deleted is undefined behavior, until that pointer has been reassigned.)

Comment: For example, after `delete ptr;` add these lines: `ptr = nullptr; anotherPtr = nullptr;` then you can `if (anotherPtr) cout << "Data using another pointer after deletion: " << anotherPtr->getData() << endl;`, which the if-expression will test false, and the true-arm will not be executed.  Disaster averted.

Comment: @Eljay disaster was averted, but OTOH if the latter code actually *needed* to use the object, then the program isn't doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: See [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106614/12002570)

Answer (score 4):

There is no one simple answer to this issue. You're asking how to avoid a [CWE-416: Use After Free](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html) bug, and there is a wide realm of solutions:

1. Detect Use After Free bugs using runtime analysis (e.g. sanitizers such as `-fsanitize=address,undefined`)

   - [Using Address Sanitizer or other Undefined Behavior Sanitizers in Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70003639/5740428)
2. Detect Use After Free using static analysis and/or compiler warnings, if possible.

   - [Does GCC have features to detect use-after-free bugs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69440983/5740428)
3. Don't use `new`/`delete` directly, but use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`. If used properly, these wrappers make it impossible to accidentally use a pointer after it has been freed.

   - [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/5740428)

Of these, the most effective solution is smart pointers. They model unique/shared ownership, and unless you break it by `release()`ing/`get()`ing the raw pointer, it is impossible to write a Use After Free bug. Runtime checks and static analysis can be seen as PPE (personal protective equipment) for when you've already written a bug.
[image]
*Image source: Infographic by [NIOSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_for_Occupational_Safety_and_Health), see also [Wikipedia: Hierarchy of hazard controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_of_hazard_controls)*

Specifically in your example, using smart pointers it would look like:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(5);

// no need to delete a std::unique_ptr by hand

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> anotherPtr = ptr; // ERROR, cannot copy a std::unique_ptr
// alternatively:
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> another = std::move(ptr); // OK, can move
```

In the end, it's not possible to make your original code not UB. However, you can use smart pointers to prevent the mistake, or you can use static/runtime checks to catch it.

To be fair, if you use `ptr` after moving to `another`, you have written a "Use After Move" bug. However, a moved-from `std::unique_ptr` stores a `nullptr`, so the bug is slightly more noticeable.

Comment: I agree that PPE is the least effective approach here.

Answer (score 2):

Use smartpointers to avoid undefined behaviour. I modified your example. Here it makes use of `shared_ptr`.

Instead of your explicit `delete`, an attempt to delete occurs at the end of scope `}`, where `ptr` goes out of scope. But since at that moment, another reference to the object still exists (held by `anotherPtr`), the object does not get deleted.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct MyClass {
  int data;
  MyClass(int d) : data(d) {}
  int getData() const { return data; }
};

int main() {
shared_ptr<MyClass> anotherPtr; // Declare a smartpointer in this scope
{   
  auto ptr = make_shared<MyClass>(5);
  cout << "ptr data: " << ptr->getData() 
       << ", use_count: " << ptr.use_count() << endl;
   
  anotherPtr = shared_ptr<MyClass>(ptr); 
  cout << "ptr data: " << ptr->getData() << ", use_count: " 
       << ptr.use_count() << endl;   
} // ptr goes out of scope

  cout << "anotherPtr data: " << anotherPtr->getData() 
       << ", use_count: " << anotherPtr.use_count() << endl;   
  return 0;
} // references:0, object deleted
```

Comment: print `ptr.use_count()` instead of commenting the snippet.

Comment: Indeed, printing `use_count` would show that neither shared_ptr has 2 references, and thus reveal a bug.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer.